# Connect a new node via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to move data from one cluster to a new cluster without downtime.

So far, I have one node on the old cluster (this is a test setup) that's on a private subnet. I have a bastion host on that network that I connect through. My new cluster also has one node, and again, is behind a bastion, so inaccessible directly.

I was hoping I'd be able to create an SSH tunnel from my new cluster machine that connects to the machine in the old cluster (so something like localhost:9300 ==> remote:9300), and then be able to set the following in my elasticsearch.yml:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
network.publish_host: 127.0.0.1
network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1
```

I've tried this, but all I'm seeing is `bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9301]}`

Has anyone managed to connect two clusters over an SSH tunnel with success?

Comment: [This article](https://t37.net/migrate-your-es-cluster-from-one-continent-to-another-without-downtime.html) might help

Comment: Thanks for the link @Val - I spotted that the other day, but it's the connection part that I'm having a problem with.

Comment: Then [this other one](http://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops) should definitely help.